# Portfolio website colors and font suggestions

Tags: website-design, color, portfolio

This is my first time on this website and I wanted to get some suggestions for my portfolio website.

I just bought the domain so I'm using my IP Address. Here is my website robsoriano.xyz

My website is not yet finished, but before everything I want get some suggestions from you guys about the colors, font sizes and everything so I can make it better before going live.

I'm using MaterializeCSS and Angular by the way

Comment: Please take a look at our [critique requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682/2611) and edit your question to match. Otherwise your question may be closed

Answer (score 1):

Your portfolio should represent *you*, asking others for suggestions would defeat the purpose of having your own portfolio.

Look at portfolios of artists you like and try to list whatever you think is positive about their website. Use this list to come up with a style for your portfolio that fits you.